# Find the norm/magnitude of 2 cross products of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, normed-spaces, cross-product

[image]

Hi everyone, the question above is for my linear algebra assignment and it had me thinking a lot. I am not sure how to proceed. My attempt was to find the norm of u, which is 1/2, and the norm of v, which is 2. (correct me if I'm wrong).

However, I don't how to proceed when the vector is in the norm notation.

I thank everyone in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\vec a \times (\vec b \times \vec c) = \vec b(\vec a\cdot\vec c)-\vec c (\vec a \cdot \vec b).$$
Therefore,
$$\vec u \times (\vec u \times \vec v) = \vec u(\vec u\cdot\vec v)-\vec v (\vec u \cdot \vec u) = -\frac{1}{4}\vec v \implies \|\vec u \times (\vec u \times \vec v)\| = \frac{1}{4}\|\vec v\|=?$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out that property. I will note it. Do you know where I can find its derivation?

Comment: Just google the proof of vector triple product. You will find many.